# How to Set value of object in SQL Server with condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to Set value of variable in SQL Server with condition?
For example

```
Declare @check as int;
Declare @email as varchar(50);

if(@check!=0){
set @email='abc@gmail.com';
else{
set @email='';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Begin instead of { and END instead of }

```
Declare @check as int;
Declare @email as varchar(50);

if(@check!=0)
BEGIN
    set @email='abc@gmail.com';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    set @email='';
END
```

It's not mandatory to have BEGIN and END but recommended for readability and easy understanding

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
if @check <> 0
    SET @email = 'abc@gmail.com'
else
    SET @email = ''
```

Have a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql) about `IF...ELSE...` in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use CASE WHEN ...

```
SELECT @email = CASE WHEN @check <> 0 THEN 'abc@gmail.com' else '' END
```